# How to implement quadrant into core chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

```
    <html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 var a=4;
    var b=8;

    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Age', 'Weight'],
          [ a,      b]

        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Assessing Value/Risk of a Contract',
          hAxis: {title: 'Risk', minValue: 0, maxValue: 40},
          vAxis: {title: 'Value', minValue: 0, maxValue: 40},
          legend: 'none'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

thsi is the google chart which i create from the help of google chart.i want a quadrant in the middle of the core chart and i tried but cant find any answer.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

*sounds like* you want to shade a specific area of the chart

this can be accomplished using a combo chart, with an area series for the quadrant

in order to draw a box, which starts above the x-axis, two area series are needed...

using the option --> `isStacked: true`
the first area series is used to create space between the x-axis and the quadrant
and is given a color of --> `'transparent'`

the second area series is used to shade the quadrant

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Age', 'Weight', 'Quad-Bottom', 'Quad-Top'],
    [4, 8, null, null],  // <-- scatter series data
    [2, null, 4, 12],    // <-- quadrant data
    [6, null, 4, 12]     // <-- quadrant data
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Assessing Value/Risk of a Contract',
    hAxis: {title: 'Risk', minValue: 0, maxValue: 40},
    vAxis: {title: 'Value', minValue: 0, maxValue: 40},
    legend: 'none',
    seriesType: 'scatter',
    series: {
      0: {
        color: '#e64a19',
        pointShape: {
          type: 'star',
          sides: 4,
          dent: 0.5
        },
        pointSize: 12,
        pointsVisible: true,
        type: 'scatter'
      },
      1: {
        areaOpacity: 1,
        color: 'transparent',
        type: 'area'
      },
      2: {
        areaOpacity: 1,
        color: '#b2dfdb',
        type: 'area'
      }
    },
    isStacked: true
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```